# How are permissions determined for filesystems on the node, i.e., not mounted?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

I'm trying to set up an app deployment on Kubernetes. I have an image that when deployed unpacks files to /opt/app. This filesystem is not mounted on a pvc.

I was provided 2 test systems running Kubernetes 1.27.1, which I was told were setup the same. For test purposes, I am running on a single node at the moment (the control plane), so the kubelet and everything is on the host.

My pod yaml in both systems is the same, including the securityContext, which sets runAsUser and fsGroup to the same values (my user).

However, on one test system, the /opt/app folder is being created with permissions rwxrwxrwx, while on the other test system, the permissions are rwxrwxr-x. The owner/group is the same on both systems.

##### goal

I would like to set /opt/app in both systems to rwxrwxrwx.

After googling a lot and reading here, I thought it would be via fsGroup, but my fsGroup is set the same on both systems, so maybe that's only for mounted volumes?

How do I control the permissions on non-mounted filesystems?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by the setup: each container has an isolated filesystem, and an image normally comes with its application preinstalled.  There wouldn't normally be a startup-time "unpack" step, and if there was, it'd be to the container's private filesystem space.  Where does the host directory come in, and why?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze Unpack was probably the wrong word here. There is no host directory; I was just trying to make clear that it's running on the control plane. /opt/app is a directory inside the pod, and I am trying to figure out why its permissions might be different on one machine vs another. I realize it's a broad topic, but I'm just fishing for ideas on where to look as everything I've checked so far was unsuccessful.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: Normally I would, but it's proprietary company code. I guess I was hoping for something like fsGroup where I could change a setting and force certain default permissions on the node filesystem inside the container.